# overriding boolean nosetests config on command line

Tags: boolean, nose

I am using nosetests, and I have a boolean config parameter in the tc-file:

```
config['clear_state'] = True
```

And I confirmed that it is of a boolean type:

```
[2016-02-12 16:13:55,624] [INFO] [__init__:teardown:34] clear_state: True
[2016-02-12 16:13:55,624] [INFO] [__init__:teardown:35] type of clear_state: <type 'bool'>
```

However, when I tried overriding it on the command line (--tc=clear_state:False), it is treated as a string:

```
[2016-02-12 16:25:56,555] [INFO] [__init__:teardown:34] clear_state: False
[2016-02-12 16:25:56,555] [INFO] [__init__:teardown:35] type of clear_state: <type 'str'>
```

My question is how I can override a boolean config parameter, and preserving it as a boolean type.

Here is some additional information.

The nosetests command is run inside a script as

```
nosetests -s -w `dirname $0` -c conf/run/all.cfg --xunit-file=all.xml --tests=./src/python/testcase/DeployOnly.py --tc=clear_state:False
```

all.cfg looks something like:

```
[nosetests]
tc-format=python
with-xunit=True
tc-file=conf/env/config.py
quiet=True
logging-level=DEBUG
logging-format=[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(module)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s
detailed-errors=True
```

And config.py is where clear_state is set.